# Embedded Database with take fast multiple writes

Tags: c#, wpf, database, sqlite

I am creating an C# WPF application that intake RS232 data and store all data to an embedded database in relatively high speed (hundreds per second). The application does two things concurrently:

1. take RS232 data and store to the database
2. plot the data from the database.

I consider SQLite because my application required embedded database and it's a single user application. But storing and graphing the data (it could be storing current data and plotting data of yesterday's) requires concurrent Read and Write to the database. I heard SQLite get lock up on one query and canot process multiple query concurrently. Is that true? If so what other embedded database supports multiple writes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, a few things.

First, yes SQLite is thread safe, even though the author is not enthusiastic about it. Read about it here: http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6.

Second, you mentioned "fast" as being hundreds of inserts per second. SQLite can easily reach 30,000 inserts per second if you wrap everything in a transaction. I say this not because it was really your question, but more because knowing this may help your decision (as it redefines what is considered "fast").

Comment: I am sure multiple write is not possible in SQLite. But does "thread safe" mean it can have one write and multiple read at least?

Comment: @KMC - Sqlite supports transactions so that is your means of concurrency control (which I suspect is what you mean by thread safety). Sqlite is thread-safe as long as you don't share connections across threads. Also note that that Sqlite only supports database-level locking, effectively limiting you to only one writer at a timer regardless of the number of connections.

Answer (score 3):

[Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index.html) has non-blocking writes and has a reputation for being speedy.

Very interestingly, [it can be used as a drop in replacement for SQLite](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/sql-160887.html).

> applications written to the SQLite
>   version 3 API can switch to using
>   Oracle Berkeley DB with no code
>   changes, by re-linking against the
>   Berkeley DB SQLite library. The
>   application-level behavior of the two
>   products is identical, but the
>   advanced features of Berkeley DB
>   provide SQLite applications improved
>   performance, concurrency, scalability,
>   and reliability.

That sounds like it would fit the bill quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Check out RavenDB.  http://www.ravendb.net/ it would be fairly easy to run some tests with it and see if it will handle your requirements.